# Get domain name RegEx

Tags: regex

What need a template RegEx to get a domain name.

For example, i have:

```
lifenews.ru
www.forbes.com
goo.gl
ya.ru
```

and get:

```
lifenews
forbes
goo
ya
```

Comment: Do you care about examples like http://www.bbc.co.uk or http://www.nsw.gov.au/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(?:www\.)?(\w+)\./', $url, $matches);
$host = $matches[1];
```

This works and, as far as I can tell, it accounts for someone putting `www` or not.

Comment: This assumes that the part of the domain name of interest will either be the first or will follow a `www.`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^(?:.*(?=\..*\..*).)?([^.]+)
```

[Demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zH5jG7).

The first part (`(?:.*(?=\..*\..*).)?`) will consume everything before (a sequence of words with two dots, like) `abc.com` in `www.stuff.abc.com`. The next part (`([^.]+)`) matches `abc`.

Comment: This will fail on domains in countries which use multiple levels, such as [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk) or [New South Wales](http://www.nsw.gov.au/)

Comment: @ClickRick You are right. I didn't have those cases in mind - didnt think, mistakenly, that was the intention of the question. A regex to predict those cases, though, without enumerating them (as the accepted answer does, or the answer in the marked-as-duplicate question) is not possible. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript w/o regex:

```
var parts = "www.forbes.com".split('.');
parts.pop();//first level domain
var domain = parts.pop(); //second level domain
```